# How to get current month firstdate and lastdate in postgres sql query

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp-with-timezone, sql-date-functions

I want to get first and last dates of current month (Like 30th or 31st).How to get this one by using postgress sql query.

Comment: You should flag this and migrate to [dba.se]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First day is easy...

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE);
```

Last day isn't much more difficult either.

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month - 1 day';
```